# jBoss thread count increaed after upgrading haproxy from 1.5dev21 to 1.5.1

Tags: haproxy, jboss-4.0.x

I upgraded my haproxy from 1.5dev21 to 1.5.1 stable version with same configuartion. At the backend, I am using jBoss.
As soon as we upgraded, I encountered serious issue regarding jBoss thread counts. It has been increased tremendously.
After rollback to 1.5dev21, everything works fine.
Please find my below configuration file of haproxy. Kindly suggest any changes required to migrate/upgrade to 1.5.1

---

global
        daemon
        maxconn         20000

defaults
        mode http
        timeout connect 15000ms
        timeout client 50000ms
        timeout server 50000ms
        timeout queue 60s
        stats enable
        stats refresh 5s

backend backend_http
        mode http
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        balance leastconn
        option forceclose
        option persist
        option redispatch
        option  forwardfor
        server server3 192.168.58.211:80 cookie server3_cokkie maxconn 1024 check
        server server4 192.168.58.212:80 cookie server4_cookie maxconn 1024 check
        acl force_sticky_server3 hdr_sub(server3_cookie) TEST=true
        force-persist if force_sticky_server3
        acl force_sticky_server4 hdr_sub(server4_cookie) TEST=true
        force-persist if force_sticky_server4
        rspidel  ^Server:.*
        rspidel  ^X-Powered-By:.*
        rspidel  ^AMF-Ver:.*

listen frontend_http *:80
       mode http
       maxconn 20000
       default_backend backend_http

listen frontend_https
       mode http
       maxconn 20000
       bind *:443 ssl crt /opt/haproxy-ssl/conf/ssl/testsite.pem
       reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
       reqadd X-Forwarded-Protocol:\ https
       reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443
       reqadd X-Forwarded-SSL:\ on
       acl valid_domains hdr_end(host) -i gateway.testsite.com www.testsite.com m.testsite.com
       redirect scheme http  if !valid_domains
       default_backend backend_http if valid_domains

---

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the haproxy manual, may be of help:

Option "http-tunnel" disables any HTTP processing past the first request and
  the first response. This is the mode which was used by default in versions
  1.0 to 1.5-dev21. It is the mode with the lowest processing overhead, which
  is normally not needed anymore unless in very specific cases such as when
  using an in-house protocol that looks like HTTP but is not compatible, or
  just to log one request per client in order to reduce log size. Note that
  everything which works at the HTTP level, including header parsing/addition,
  cookie processing or content switching will only work for the first request
  and will be ignored after the first response.